# Swift TableView insert row below button clicked

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am new to Swift and I am using Swift 4.2 . I have a TableView with a label and button . When I press a button I would like to add a new row directly below the row in which the button was clicked . Right now when I click a button the new row gets added to the bottom of the TableView every time. I have been looking at posts on here but haven't been able to get it working this is my code base . I have a method called **RowClick** I get the indexpath of the row that was clicked but do not know how to use that to get the new row to appear directly below the clicked row .

```
class ExpandController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var TableSource: UITableView!


    var videos: [String] = ["FaceBook","Twitter","Instagram"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TableSource.delegate = self
        TableSource.dataSource = self
        TableSource.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



    @IBAction func RowClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? ExpandTVC else {
            return
        }

        let indexPath = TableSource.indexPath(for: cell)
        InsertVideoTitle(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
    func InsertVideoTitle(indexPath: IndexPath?)
    {
        videos.append("Snapchat")
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: videos.count - 1, section: 0)
        TableSource.beginUpdates()
        TableSource.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        TableSource.endUpdates()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = TableSource.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExpandTVC") as! ExpandTVC
        cell.Title.text = videoTitle

        cell.ButtonRow.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.ButtonRow.setTitle("Rows",for: .normal)

        return cell
    }

}
```

This is how my table looks I clicked the Facebook Rows button and it appended the string SnapChat . The Snapchat label should appear in a row below Facebook instead . Any suggestions would be great !

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your current code calls `append` to add the new item at the end of the array. What you want to do is insert a new row at `indexPath.row+1`. `Array` has an `insert(element,at:)` function.

You have to handle the case where the user has tapped the last row and not add 1 to avoid an array bounds error:

```
func InsertVideoTitle(indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let targetRow = indexPath.row < videos.endIndex ? indexPath.row+1 : indexPath.row 
    videos.insert("Snapchat" at:targetRow)
    let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: targetRow, section: 0)
    TableSource.beginUpdates()
    TableSource.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
    TableSource.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks a lot that worked . I'm guessing that when adding multiple rows such as videos.insert(contentsOf: ["Snapchat","Tik Tok"], at: targetRow) that the section has to be updated too .

Comment: Yes, you would need to ensure you insert the right rows into your table view to keep it consistent with the changes to the array

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution without re-writing this whole thing would be adding 1 to the current row of the IndexPath you captured from the action.

```
let indexPath = TableSource.indexPath(for: cell)
        var newIndexPath = indexPath;
        newIndexPath.row += 1;
        InsertVideoTitle(indexPath: newIndexPath);
```

I did this from memory because I am not near an IDE, so take a look at the change and apply that change if needed in any other location.

```
class ExpandController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var TableSource: UITableView!


    var videos: [String] = ["FaceBook","Twitter","Instagram"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TableSource.delegate = self
        TableSource.dataSource = self
        TableSource.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }



    @IBAction func RowClick(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let cell = sender.superview?.superview as? ExpandTVC else {
            return
        }

        let indexPath = TableSource.indexPath(for: cell)
        var newIndexPath = indexPath;
        newIndexPath.row += 1;
        InsertVideoTitle(indexPath: newIndexPath);
    }
    func InsertVideoTitle(indexPath: IndexPath?)
    {
        videos.append("Snapchat")
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: videos.count - 1, section: 0)
        TableSource.beginUpdates()
        TableSource.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        TableSource.endUpdates()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return videos.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let videoTitle = videos[indexPath.row]
        let cell = TableSource.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ExpandTVC") as! ExpandTVC
        cell.Title.text = videoTitle

        cell.ButtonRow.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.ButtonRow.setTitle("Rows",for: .normal)

        return cell
    }

}
```